# CW list of expert opinions about an unsolved problem

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

In [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1335/a-new-p-vs-np-poll-closed) I wrote the following comment.

> I voted to close as I don't consider the question objectively answerable. I could imagine a version that would fit with the site, though. A community wiki like: "Please post links to opinions of TCS experts about the P/NP problem." Maybe. for example, I've heard that Terence Tao considers P/NP to be a 500-year problem, but I've never seen a concrete reference. It would be interesting to collect such things.

Now I'm wondering if I was off-base.  It seems sorta-kinda in the big-list category to me, and if someone tries to hijack by posting multiple links to a crank, the community will vote those answers down.  But it's not as clear-cut as links to refereed papers or videos of invited talks.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the key difference between this and other potential big list questions. A good close-by question is the one on what papers everyone should read. That question works because the answer is a union of specific nuggets, each having nontrivial content (paper A, paper B, and so on). It's opinionated, but the answers are concrete.

For P vs NP, it seems to me that the answers themselves, while being opinionated, are less likely to have factual content. The question is phrased "what do you think of P vs NP", and so the answers will be of the form "I think (= or $\ne$) because of X", where "X" is some subjective reasoning based on the evidence that we do have. X is not a specific list of concrete thoughts though.

Even if the question were made more concrete like "What are current plausible lines of attack", there's really only one answer - Mulmuley's approach. So either way, there's nothing here except a way of letting people let off some steam, and I don't think that's what this site should be about.